# SQL Server 2008 FileStream on a Web Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis

I've been developing a site using ASP.NET MVC, and have decided to use the new SQL Server 2008 `FILESTREAM` facility to store files 'within' the database rather than as separate entities.  While initially working within VS2008 (using a trusted connection to the database), everything was fine and dandy.  Issues arose, however, when I shifted the site to IIS7 and changed over to SQL authentication on the database.

It seems that streaming a `FILESTREAM` doesn't work with SQL authentication, only with Windows authentication.  Given this, what is the best practice to follow?

1. Is there a way to force this sort of thing to work under SQL authentication?
2. Should I add `NETWORK SERVICE` as a database user and then use Trusted authentication?
3. Should I create another user, and run both the IIS site and the database connection under this?
4. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/Configure_Filestream_in_SQL_Server_2008_p1.aspx). I don't know a whole lot about FileStreaming and security, but there are a couple of interesting options in the FileStreaming setup such as allowing remote connections and allow remote clients to access FileStreaming

Comment: Yeah, I've got that covered, but thanks for the link. I'm more concerned with best practice regarding authentication using FILESTREAM from an IIS-based website.